# change the contents of a global variable from another module in Julia

Tags: global-variables, julia

I have two modules, one called mainLoop and the other called subroutines:

```
module mainLoop
using subroutines
export memory
memory = zeros(Int,10)
foo(UInt32(17))
print(memory,"\n")

end

module subroutines
using mainLoop
export foo

function foo(x::UInt32)
  mainLoop.memory[1]=x
end
end
```

I can't figure out how to change the contents of the array called memory from the subroutine module. I don't have the option of passing the array as an argument to the function so I have to use a global variable. In the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/variables-and-scoping/), it states:

> "Modules can introduce variables of other modules into their scope through the using or import statements or through qualified access using the dot-notation, i.e. each module is a so-called namespace. Note that variable bindings can only be changed within their global scope and not from an outside module."

By variable bindings, does it mean that you can't change the variable contents?

Comment: Don't use global variables, just pass memory as an argument to each subroutine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A module can only change its own global variables, not those of other modules. There is a way, of course, to force a module to change its own global variables — by running toplevel code through `eval`.

```
julia> module A
           x = 1
           y = 2
       end
A

julia> module B
           using ..A
           println("A.x = ", A.x)  # can access
           A.y = 3  # can't set
       end
A.x = 1
ERROR: cannot assign variables in other modules

julia> A.y
2

julia> module C
           using ..A
           println("A.x = ", A.x)  # can access
           @eval(A, y = 3)  # set y = 3, FROM module A
           println("A.y = ", A.y)  # value of y updated
       end
A.x = 1
A.y = 3
C

julia> A.y
3
```

However, [mutating global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) — especially *some other module's global state* — is a code smell and should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Note that variable bindings can only be changed within their global scope and not from an outside module."*

Is the module written by you? Because then you can just easily, instead of changing the binding "manually", create a function that does that for you and export that function along with the rest, i.e within what your module regards as its global scope

Answer (score 0):

Globals introduce complexity. Specifically, 1) compiler optimizations are tougher to prove correct and 2) code becomes harder to reason about for developers. Changing a global in another API adds another layer of complexity. Possible? Yes. Advisable? Hardly, but never say never. If desired,

- [ensure type-stability](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-untyped-global-variables)
- [be explicit about the API](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Prefer-exported-methods-over-direct-field-access).

**I. Update a variable in another module**

One can modify the field of a struct to set a `const`, and update it via `global`.

```
module A
export f, updatey!

mutable struct Const ϕ::Int end
const y = Const(1)
updatey!(value) = global y.ϕ = value

f(x) = x + y.ϕ
end

using .A

f(5)          # 6
updatey!(10)
f(5)          # 15

A.y
#> Main.A.Const(2)
```

Try removing `const`, replacing `global` with `@eval`, or `y` as an integer. Results of `BenchmarkTools.@btime f($5)` show 1) allocations, 2) unoptimized, 3) slow updates.

**II. Assign and use from another module**

Use `let` to modify and capture global variables in other modules, and define a closure for inclusion in the current module.

```
module B
export g₁, g₂
using ..A

let 
    updatey!(5)
    value = A.f(1)
    global g₁(z) = value * z
end
let 
    updatey!(10)
    value = A.f(1)
    global g₂(z) = value * z
end
end

using .B
g₁(3)      # 18 [ (1 + 5 ) * 3 ]
g₂(3)      # 33 [ (1 + 10) * 3 ]
```

---

**Further reading**

- [Against globals & alternatives](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-correctly-define-and-use-global-variables-in-the-module-in-julia/65720)
- [What, why & how](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.01950.pdf#section.3) of type stability in Julia